# How to run a custom angular library for local development containing multiple modules

Tags: angular, frontend, angular-ui-router, typescript2.0

Let me explain my problem statement in details.
I have a main application (basically a skeleton angular 14 application) where I have multiple libraries which i install inside the library. (step 1--> create build for that library, step 2--> npm pack, step 3--> npm i <library_name> --save-dev in main application to run that library.)

Now to run the library locally I made few changes

1. In app.component.html specify the selector for my component
2. Run ng build <library_name> --watch { this --watch tag makes the build responsive that so that after every change the build is automatically updated.

Now my concern is I have a library which contains multiple modules ( basically lazy-loading is implemented in that library) since it contains mupliple files (say a,b,c,d). Can someone please specify the work through to run library with multiple module locally?